# Sklearn logistic regression optimized on a profit loss matrix with unbalanced classes

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I need to train a Logistic Regression in Sklearn with different profit-loss weights between classes.

The positive class is a loss. Meaning that each time a negative happens, it costs the company, say 1.000$. This obviously happens to both True Positive and False Negative cases.

On the other hand each negative case (both True Negative and False Positive) makes the company gain 50$.

The question is: how do I train, say,  a Logistic Regression classifier in SkLearn to maximizes the prifit?

A further complication is that the positive and negative classes are unbalanced meaning that the Positives represent a 5% of overall sample size while the Negatives rerpesent a 95% of overall sample size.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Optimising your profit is the same as optimising accuracy, you want as many TP and TN compared to FP and FN.

Comment: It is I am not sure about it:

Comment: It is what I was wandering too but I am not convinced it is the same thing since a FN costs much more than a FP. SAS and KOnime allows to make prifit/loss optimizations by assigning different costs and gains to the classes. I guess that I could do the same in python but I do not know how....

Comment: You can make custom scorers in sklearn, see the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html) and you can also use class weights in most classifiers. You can't optimise Logistic Regression to a custom scorer though, though you can do it in LogisticRegressionCV